# jQuery background changing with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-frontend

here thisid stores the id of html element. and I want to change its background colour using the following code

```js
let thisid = 'test';
$("a#" + thisid).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test" href="#">Hello world!</a><br/>
<a id="test2" href="#">Goodbye all</a>
```

this is not working, but it works if I remove thisid and write it in following way

```
 $("a").css("background-color","yellow");
```

but it selects all with tag

below is what actually I want to do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // hide all questions
        $("h1").hide();
        // display first question
        $("h1#1").show();
        // show selected question
        $("a").bind('click',function(){

            let thisid = $(this).attr('id');

            $("h1").hide();
            $("h1#"+thisid).show();
            $("a#"+thisid).css("background-color","yellow");
        });

    });
```

Comment: Your code *should* work as is (although since `id` values are supposed to be unique, the `a` in front of the `id` is superfluous). Perhaps `thisid` doesn't have what you think it should in it?

Comment: I've converted your code into a snippet which shows that it works fine.

Comment: your code works as expected

Comment: I added full code which didn't work as expected :(

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the jQuery function (`$()`) is being treated as a CSS selector.  Since you're trying to find an element by ID, you need to *start* the selector with an octothorpe (`#`).  Starting with a character selects by tag type.  Not having your html handy, I'm guessing the actual problem is that the element with ID `thisid` is not an `<a>` tag.  (You're actually selecting "any a tag with id `thisid`", but since an ID is unique including the tag type selector is redundant)

You should be able to do something more like this:

```js
let thisid = "two"
$("#"+thisid).css("background-color","yellow");
thisid = "three"
// won't work, element with id `three` is not an 'a' tag
$("a#"+thisid).css("background-color","green"); 
thisid = "four"
$("div#"+thisid).css("background-color","blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
<div id="four">four</div>
```

Comment: You have not added your HTML, which is probably where the problem is.